# Entering a backtick with the Swype keyboard

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s, customization, swype

I have a Samsung Galaxy S and use the Swype keyboard by default (OK, I'm addicted to it).  Using Swype, I can't find the backtick character, `` ` ``, which limits my ability to answer questions or add comments on these SE sites.  It exists in the Android keyboard, but going to *Settings > Locale and text* midway through entering a post is a pain, especially if I want to switch back to Swype afterwards so I have to do it twice.

I think I've done an exhaustive search of all the characters available (long press, extra-long-press, symbol key, etc.).  Does the backtick exist in the Swype keyboard and I just haven't noticed it?  If not, is there a way that I can customize the Swype keyboard to include the backtick?

Comment: BTW, it does look like the swype developers have been aware of the problem for the past 7 months. I would have thought it would have been fixed by now. swype.uservoice.com/forums/55960-swype-for-android-beta/… – Will Z Oct 19 at 13:25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only need the backtick for when you're entering code on StackExchange sites, then there's actually no reason to type the character.

Any time you're in a Question or Answer box, there's a set of icons just above the box, pressing the `101 010` button puts a pair of matching backticks into the text box at the current cursor location, with some replacable text in between, now just type over that text with Swype (or paste over). Works perfectly on my Galaxy S with Swype enabled.

**Edit**
For more recent versions of Swype, see [MiquelFire's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/entering-a-backtick-with-the-swype-keyboard/12579#12579) where the backtick is now available as an extended character on the `.'` key beside the space bar.

Comment: Hah! I generally have my phone in landscape mode when using the web browser so I never even see those buttons, but it's easy enough to turn it 90 degrees.  I just realized too that I can type a comment into the Answer box, then cut and past it into the comment box!

Comment: Seems that backtick have been there on Extra-Long-Press-on-"." at least from SWYPE version 2.72 that is on my Samsung Galaxy S2.

Answer (score 10):

Another confirmation that the back tick isn't on Swype. But, you don't need to dig that deep to switch.. Long press in the input area, choose "Input method" and then you can select the Samsung or Android keyboards. Another long press and two clicks and you are back to Swype.

Comment: +1. Didn't know you could change keyboards like that.  One of these days I'll have to RTFM. :)

Answer (score 8):

Holding down the `'.` key will get you a menu of extra characters to type. I saw the ` there.

2012-10-09 Update: I recently check with the beta version of Swype, and noticed that the ` had moved to `r4` key, but my original answer is still valid for the version of Swype built into my phone. Future versions of Swype may move special keys around, and you may need to hunt them down.

Comment: Confirmed that the latest version of Swype does allow this.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used that symbol on my phone before, but looked in my version of Swype, not the Galaxy S version but still the latest update, and didn't find the backtick. Looks like you will have to send an email to the Swype team and hope they listen, or get around using it. Sorry man.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.